# How to append the img alt to an li

Tags: jquery, html

Hey guys, me again, I know I asked something similar a little while ago, but the function that i need for this it is slightly different, this time I have an ul element with img tags embedded inside a tags. What I need is when the image is clicked to populate an li element, but is the next or last image is clicked I need the same li element populated with the update content. Please find the html below. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="filter">
    <div class="heading" id="activityLevel">
        <p><a href="#">Activity Level</a></p>
        <a href="#" target="_self">modify</a>                  
    </div>
    <div class="add-filters" id="addActivityLevel">
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="#" class="btn-close"></a>
            <h4 class="title-filtery">Filtery By:</h4>
            <ul class="activity-level">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/shore-excursions/btn-activity-level-easy.gif" alt="Activity Level Easy" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="../images/shore-excursions/btn-activity-level-moderal.gif" alt="Activity Level  Moderate" /></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#"><img src="../images/shore-excursions/btn-activity-level-extreme.gif" alt="Activity Level Extreme" /></a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. iaculis in magna. In ut dolor a lacus adipiscing molestie.</p>
            <div class="btn-holder clearfix">
                <input type="button" class="btn-cancel" value="" />
                <input type="button" class="btn-update" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- filters -->
    <div class="hidden-filters" id="hiddenActivityLevel">
        <p>Filtering by:</p>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How's your jQuery code look so far? Where'd you get stuck?

Comment: Populate which LI element? The description you've given makes it a bit difficult to understand exactly what you want to do. Could you provide your current code and/or an exact description of what you expect to occur under a number of different scenarios?

Comment: @treeface The element I'm trying to populate is ul under id="hiddenActivityLevel"

Comment: Ah ha...that makes a bit more sense now. So let's work this idea through a little more. You click on the first image and you expect there to be a new LI under that empty UL with the alt text of the image, correct? Will this be the only LI in this UL? Do you always want only this LI populated with the image alt text when you click on the image? This is what I mean by a detailed description...what behavior do you expect....in detail. What happens when you click image 1 then image 2? Then image 3? Or if you first click image 3, then 1, then 2? Do you expect the same thing every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('img').click(
    function(){
        if ($('#hiddenActivityLevel ul li:first').length) {
          $('#hiddenActivityLevel ul li:first').text($(this).attr('alt'));
        }
        else {
          $('<li />').appendTo('#hiddenActivityLevel ul').text($(this).attr('alt'));
        }
        return false;
    }
  )
}
);
```

A couple of pointers:

This will react to a click on every image element, the `return false` is there specifically for those images inside of `a` tags; but you'd do well to specify, by class or parentage (`$('ul li a img')` for example) to narrow the range of affected elements.

In the above, also, the selector `$('hiddenActivityLevel ul li:first')` is used to select only *one* `li`, though you could use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to achieve the same (for example: `$('hiddenActivityLevel ul li').eq(3)` will select the fourth `li`, JS arrays are zero-based, remember).

I would, though, *strongly advise* you to place an `id` on the specific `li` you want to populate and have it present in the DOM on-load, rather than creating it on the fly.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by:

> but is the next or last image is clicked I need the same li element populated with the update content.

But I've taken it to mean 'I want the same `li` to be updated with the `alt` text of the clicked-image regardless of *which* image is clicked.'